# Make error: *** multiple target patterns. Stop

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, msys

this is my first time posting here, so sorry if this ends up in the wrong place. I am trying to compile some code I've downloaded from a GitHUb repository and am running make from the MSYS Shell. There is a problem with the makefile that has the common make rules. When I run make, I get the following error:
C:\Mios32/include/makefile/common.mk:143: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.

Since I'm a complete beginner with regard to make and makefile, I can't find the problem. Here's the code from common.mk file from line 152 to 154:

```
# rule to create .elf file            
$(PROJECT_OUT)/$(PROJECT).elf: $(ALL_OBJS)
     @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(ALL_OBJS) $(LIBS) $(LDFLAGS) -o$@
```

Lmk if I need to upload the whole common makefile. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation on error messages in the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html).

This error means that you have a static pattern rule, with multiple patterns (`%` characters) in the target.  Your line is here:

```
 $(PROJECT_OUT)/$(PROJECT).elf: $(ALL_OBJS)
```

The only way to know what the problem is, is to find the values of the `PROJECT_OUT`, `PROJECT`, and `ALL_OBJS` variables.  No doubt they contain colon characters and/or percent characters.

The `make` program is a tool developed on UNIX, well before "driver letters", backslash as directory separators, etc. were popularized by Microsoft.  As such, its syntax is geared towards UNIX systems where `:` is not expected in pathnames, backslash is an escape character, etc.

If you want to build software on Windows that was developed for POSIX systems such as GNU/Linux and MacOS, you'll have to do some work translating pathnames between them.  You should not use drive-letter-qualified paths when working with makefiles, and you should not use any paths containing whitespace, and you should always use forward-slashes (`/`) as directory separators, never backslashes.